# How to Find the Index of an Item in a sublist of a list (python)

Tags: python, list, indexing, sublist

```
ExampleList = [['Ck'], ['Kat'], ['Arcadiusz']]

ExampleListFull = [['CK', 21, 'Male'], ['Kat', 19, 'Female'], ['Arcadiusz', 30, 'Male']]
           

User = str(input())
User = User.capitalise()

if ([User] in ExampleList) == True:
```

From *here* we want to find the Index of "User", lets go with Kat, I know it's 1, 0, 
However I want the program to be able to tell me for what ever name is
entered, this way I than can print 
`(User + '\'s', 'age is', (ExampleListFull(variable) (variable)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ExampleListFull = [['CK', 21, 'Male'], ['Kat', 19, 'Female'], ['Arcadiusz', 30, 'Male']]
User = str(input())
User = User.capitalise()
```

Here, we create a dummy list with the values of all the names. This should print `['CK', 'Kat', 'Arcadiusz']`

```
names = [value[0] for value in data]
print(names)
```

The one-line for-loop is the equivalent of doing:

```
names = []
for value in data:
    names.append(value[0])
```

Then we can print the result

```
print(names.index(name))
print("Age is", {data[names.index(name)][1]})
```

This can all be shortened to just a few lines of code like this:

```
data = [['CK', 21, 'Male'], ['Kat', 19, 'Female'], ['Arcadiusz', 30, 'Male']]

User = str(input())
User = User.capitalise()

age = data[[value[0] for value in data].index(name)][1]
# gender= data[[value[0] for value in data].index(name)][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a dictionary as you data structure here but is you need a list you could try using the index method as follow:

```
ExampleList = [['Ck'], ['Kat'], ['Arcadiusz']]

x = ExampleList.index(['Ck'])

print(x)
```

Output:

```
0
```

This returns the position at the first occurrence of the specified value

Answer (score 0):

```
ExampleList = [['Ck'], ['Kat'], ['Arcadiusz']]

ExampleListFull = [['CK', 21, 'Male'], ['Kat', 19, 'Female'], ['Arcadiusz', 30, 'Male']]

User = str(input()) 
User = User.capitalize()
for Index,string in enumerate(ExampleList):
  
  if User == ExampleList[Index][0]:

    print(User + 's', 'age is ' + str(ExampleListFull[Index][1]))
```